# comparing datetime index pandas array to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to remove any data in a pandas dataframe before a certain timestamp (i'm using now for this example)

candle_data[min] is my dataframe...

```
candle_data[min].loc[candle_data[min].index < pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), unit='ns')]
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and Timestamp
```

here is data dataframe

```
candle_data[min].loc[candle_data[min].index]
                           volume  complete        o        h        l        c
time                                                                           
2021-09-06 20:00:00+00:00     353      True  1.25344  1.25374  1.25324  1.25362
2021-09-06 20:05:00+00:00     125      True  1.25357  1.25357  1.25320  1.25338
2021-09-06 20:10:00+00:00      75      True  1.25336  1.25354  1.25332  1.25333
2021-09-06 20:15:00+00:00      70      True  1.25336  1.25356  1.25331  1.25336
2021-09-06 20:20:00+00:00      68      True  1.25333  1.25352  1.25332  1.25338
...                           ...       ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
2021-09-08 13:45:00+00:00     429      True  1.26782  1.26891  1.26758  1.26879
2021-09-08 13:50:00+00:00     363      True  1.26877  1.26901  1.26822  1.26831
2021-09-08 13:55:00+00:00     340      True  1.26829  1.26832  1.26657  1.26680
2021-09-08 14:00:00+00:00    1219      True  1.26688  1.26797  1.26460  1.26790
2021-09-08 14:05:00+00:00     654      True  1.26786  1.26858  1.26641  1.26650
[499 rows x 6 columns]
```

and this is what pd.to_datetime gives me

```
pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), unit='ns')
Timestamp('2021-09-08 14:34:37.175469')
```

I've attempted to look at other articles and google but have not managed to avoid a very similar message to this... How can i convert the timestamp to something that can be compared?

Comment: Why do you want to use Python datetime in the first place? You could just use pandas types, e.g. `pd.Timestamp('2021-09-08 14:34:37.175469')` or `pd.Timestamp('now')`

Answer (score 0):

It's ok whether you use `pd.Timestamp` object (created by using `pd.to_datetime` method in your question) or directly Python `datetime` library. There are some difference in some cases (and I would generally prefer to stick to using pandas objects when working with DataFrames), but in your case the issue lays in timezone difference.

Your index is localized (`datetime64[ns, UTC]`), but not your datetime object. It might be a bit confusing to someone because you use `utcnow` method. This method will return utc current time, but **not localized** meaning it's a **datetime object without timezone**.

Solution is easy, you can do one of the following (and you can experiment with it a bit to understand how it works):

- use index without timezone: `candle_data.index.tz_localize(None) < pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), unit='ns')`
- localize your Timestamp object: `candle_data.index < pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), unit='ns', utc=True)`
- localize your Timestamp object without using datetime: `candle_data[min].index < pd.Timestamp("now", tz="UTC")`

And there are more and more ways how to do it. And I would generally recommend to use slicing instead of such comparison to index. You could do e.g. the following:

```
candle_data[:datetime.datetime.utcnow()]
# or
candle_data[:pd.Timestamp("now")]
```

It will return all data where index datetime is less than the current time.